# Controlling the amount of list selected in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, multi-select

I have this project am working on, but there is this particular point I can't get pass through. I want to control the amount of list to be selected by the user. I want the user to select only two from the list or 3 from the list. And also, I want to validate that the user selected the amount I want the user to select.

Please help me out. This is my code so far.

```
class _LibraChoosePayState extends State<LibraChoosePay> {

  List<int> selectedService = [];
  List<dynamic> services = [
    [ Plans.electrician, Plans.electrician, "Electrician", "For electrical repairs and works. Both for offices and homes. Anywhere.", 0],

    [ Plans.mechanic, Plans.mechanic, "Electrician", "For electrical repairs and works. Both for offices and homes. Anywhere.", 0],

    [ Plans.electrician, Plans.electrician, "Electrician", "For electrical repairs and works. Both for offices and homes. Anywhere.", 1],

    [ Plans.electrician, Plans.electrician, "Electrician", "For electrical repairs and works. Both for offices and homes. Anywhere.", 0],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundLightMode,
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed:() {
                          Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, SelectPlan.idScreen);
                        },
                        icon: AppAllIcons.arrowDown
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 60,),
                      const Text(
                        "Select and Subscribe",
                        style: AppTextStyle.headerTextDarkStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: services.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap:  () {
                            setState(() {
                              //selectedService = index;
                              if(selectedService.contains(index)) {
                                selectedService.remove(index);
                              } else{
                                selectedService.add(index);
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                              color: Colors.white,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: selectedService.contains(index) ? Colors.blue : Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
                                width: 2
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                selectedService.contains(index) ?
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.blue.shade100,
                                    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                                    blurRadius: 10
                                  ) : BoxShadow(
                                    color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                                    offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                                    blurRadius: 10
                                  )
                              ]
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                selectedService.contains(index) ? Image.asset(services[index][0], width: 50,) :
                                Image.asset(services[index][1], width: 50,),
                                const SizedBox(width: 30,),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(services[index][2], style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade800,
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                      ),),
                                      Text(services[index][3], style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                      ),)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: selectedService.contains(index) ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      })
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                ]
              ),
            )
            ,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

It allows the user to select everything in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Only need to change the code is onTap

```
 onTap: () {

   int maxSelectCount = 2; // your count
   setState(() {
     //selectedService = index;
     if (selectedService.contains(index)) {
       selectedService.remove(index);
     } else {
      // Condition for selection
       if (selectedService.length < maxSelectCount) {
         selectedService.add(index);
       } else {
         ///Message you could not select more than [maxSelectCount]
       }
     }
   });
 },
```

for validation you can set on payment button click

```
   if (selectedService.isEmpty)
   {
        ///Message: You should select at least 1 service to proceed further
   }else
   {
        ///Payment code or any
   }
```

Comment: But what about the validation? Is it possible? Because the user must select before payment.

Comment: Please check the updated code @EvaristusAdimonyemma

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the selectedServices.length?

```dart
onTap: () {
   // user is deselecting a service, OK
  if (selectedServices.contains(index)) {
    setState(() {
      selectedServices.remove(index);
    });
  }
  // user is selecting a service
  else {
    // check of limit
    if (selectedServices.length == ALLOWED_LIMIT) {
      // tell user to only select at most ALLOWED_LIMIT services.
    }
    // user hasn't select allowed services limit
    else {
      setState(() {
        selectedServices.add(index);
      });
    }
  }
}
```